# Performing simple arithmetic on the value of a numeric parameter passed to a control sequence?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I am trying to define a new command to take in a a node/coordinate as the center and draw a dashed
rectangle around it. I would also like to pass a text label above the rectangle as the fourth
parameter and the position of this text needs to be just above the rectangle. So I need to
**divide** the 3rd parameter(height) by 2.

```
\newcommand{\myrect}[4]{\node[draw, thick, dashed, shape=rectangle,%
                             minimum height=#2, minimum width=#3,%
                             anchor=center] at (#1){};%
                             \node[above=#3/2 + \adjustment] % how can I do this ?
                             at (#1) {#4};}
```

Any idea on how this can be done? Ideally I would also like to make simple adjustments by **adding** a number to it.

Comment: but if you divide by 2 the result will be without units see section 94 of pgf manual -- so it would be easier to declare height and width separately just like you have declared `\adjustment`

Comment: Or, you can put the calculations inside a curly bracket with the units, e.g.: `\node[above={#3/2 + \adjustment cm} ]`

Comment: true -- the only problem being sometimes units get mixed while defining width and height -- for example (2cm, 4pt)